# Remove or replace double quotes from values of XML (specific search and replace)

Tags: xml, bash, search, replace, quotes

I have the following XML:

```
<smtng attr="bla"><desc>bla 12" bla</desc></smtng>
```

And I would like to use some command (preferably executable from bash) to replace the `"` after `12` with `&quot;`, but leave it as it is for the `attr="bla"` part...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a reason for using a character entity there. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: becouse I am converting this xml for further editing and " is making problems in later parsing ;)

Comment: No correctly functioning XML parser should have any trouble with this.

Comment: the thing is that it's not being parsed by xml parser... I know it's not smart but becouse of other parts of the project it can't be used...

Comment: Go slap whoever wrote the "parser" in the face, then make him fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work, but you should really use the proper tools.

```
sed 's|</\?desc>|\n&|g; s/\(<desc>[^"]*\)"\([^\n]*\n\)/\1\&quot;\2/g;s/\n//g' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -e $'s@<desc>@\\\n<desc>@' -e  $'s@</desc>@</desc>\\\n@' | \
while IFS=$'\n\r' read line; do
  case "${line}" in
    *"<desc>"*)
    sed 's@"@\&quot;@' <<<"${line}"
    ;;

    *)
    echo "${line}"
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Out of laziness I edited my prior answer to isolate  on its own line

Comment: Updated mine, output will actually have desc on separate lines ... which can be fixed too ... In principle I think Dennis' answer is better, but if you are going for legibility this might be easier

Comment: one more edit - somehow I missed the " replacement (I thought it was being stripped)

Answer (score 0):

Using xmlstarlet you can do the following:

```
# cf. http://www.exslt.org/str/index.html
echo '<smtng attr="bla"><desc>bla 12" bla</desc></smtng>'  | 
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//smtng/desc" -v "str:replace(.,'&quot;','&amp;quot;')" -n
```